# Is calling a table a valid operation?

Tags: lua, static-analysis

I'm very new to lua but need to program in lua for a bit.

I have the following code

```
local Events={}
Events('a')
```

From my rough understanding, `Events` is a table, and table cannot be called like a function.

I paste the above statements in Intellij Idea with Lua plugin, Intellij Idea with EmmyLua plugin, and ZeroBrane Studio. **None of the IDE statically prompts an error in the code.**

See the figure. Intellij shows a green tick, indicating no static analysis errors. ZeroBrane Studio shows no warnings or errors, until I press the run button.

[image]

https://github.com/mpeterv/luacheck says the code is OK

```
>luacheck --version
Luacheck: 0.23.0
Lua: PUC-Rio Lua 5.3
Argparse: 0.6.0
LuaFileSystem: 1.6.3
LuaLanes: 3.10.1

Total: 2 warnings / 0 errors in 1 file

>luacheck untitled.lua
Checking untitled.lua                             OK

Total: 0 warnings / 0 errors in 1 file
```

Can anyone clarify why these IDE don't statically detect this simple mistake? Can calling a table sometimes be a valid operation?

Answer (score 2):

A table can be called like a function if you give it a metatable that has a `__call` metamethod in it. [See the docs.](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#2.4)

Also, since Lua is dynamically typed, it would be difficult for a static analyzer to know that variable is non-callable when you try to call it.